# Translation of "cheesy"

Tags: traducción, adjetivos

What is the best Spanish translation of the English word "cheesy" (something inauthentic, trying too hard to be funny, cheap, shabby, etc.)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I understand "cheesy", the translation is "cursi". And it works in Hispanoamerica too, not only in Spain. "Caseoso" is out of discussion, that's for something related to "cheese".

Comment: I'd say _'cursi'_ would work 75% of the times to accurately translate _'cheesy'_. Options in other answers would suit better in some cases and should be considered as well.

Answer (score 8):

Terms I've heard:

- Cursi

ie.

> ¡Eres muy cursi!

Comment: Note, that *cursi* would be understood in Spain only.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've heard *cursi* in Mexico, too.

Comment: Also in Argentina

Comment: Also in Colombia - Cursi is used everywhere.

Comment: Also in Chile .

Comment: Yes, "cursi" is used in México too as Flimzy said.

Answer (score 2):

Cheesy has another meaning in English appart from "cursi":

- Inferior or cheap: "de mal gusto" / "cutre" (slang)
- Of a smile: "insincero"

In fact, I've only seen it used as "cutre"

Source: http://www.wordreference.com/definition/cheesy

Comment: I believe _'cutre'_ is Spain only slang.

Comment: No, 'cutre' is slang in Perú too.

Answer (score 2):

«Hortera» is also a good match

Comment: I'm native, never heard Hortera nor do I know what it means. Wouldn't recommend using it to avoid weird "What?" looks

Comment: In European Spanish is totally common (Google shows 700.000 results)

Comment: Maybe only in Spain, because I'm from south america and never heard of it. For instance, the other suggested translation, "Cursi", has 7.1 million results. Showing it's used more than 10 times more online at least

Answer (score 0):

I always think of '*cursi*' as more like '*twee*' really than '*cheesy*'.
'*Hortera*' definitely maps on better.
¡No hay parto sin dolor ni hortera sin transistor!
That was a saying in the 80s-a properly cheesy decade at the time that people now seem to have retro-fitted as cool.
Cheesy is really to do with the gap between self-image/promotion of a person/thing and its reality to the beholder.
So Julio Iglesias was Borat-level cheesy to 70s/80s english ears of a certain age but maybe was an icon of romance to their aunts/mums?
Maybe *cheesy* is 'masculine-style to excess' and *twee* is 'female-style to excess'?
Lo que tienen en comun es que en ambos casos se han pasado 3 pueblos.

A  radar for cheesiness is definitely more of an english than a spanish thing though!
Everything in moderation...

Comment: "Twee" is not a very common word at all (at least as far as my linguistic sphere is concerned) and could meaning something more specific, more like cutesy; whereas "cheesy" is extremely common and has a broader use.

Answer (score 0):

Despende del contexto. Cheesy, también puede significar "mantecoso", "pastoso", "oleoso". Hace referencia a algo denso. No veo la relación con "cursi". Más bién con alguien o algo pesado, medio cargante, difícil de tragar

Comment: Lamento decirte que tu uso de la palabra es ajeno al que le da normalmente (por lo menos en Norteamérica). Signfica normalmente algo dicho/hecho con la intención de hacer gracias, o al que se haya querido infudir de sentimentalismo o de hondura, pero que se quede corto y termine sonando mal.